# Gradle sync failed: Could not install Gradle distribution from "https://employer.jfrog.io/employer/gradle-distribution/gradle-7.0-bin.zip'

Tags: gradle, groovy, oauth-2.0, artifactory

I need employer authorized SSO to login to jfrog in the browser.

I'm not sure how exactly to enter these credentials in gradle files

I tried installing the jfrog plugin in IntelliJ and adding the URLs in JFrog global configuration, but the test connection failed.

Original repo has

```
credentials {
   username = artifactory_user
   password = artifactory_password
}
```

in settings.gradle and artifactory.gradle

I tried replacing artifactory_user with my SSO username and password with the API key generated in JFrog. Still I get the same error on

> Gradle sync failed: Could not install Gradle distribution from "http://employer.jfrog.io/employer/gradle-distribution/gradle-7.0-bin.zip'

Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm not sure how exactly to enter these credentials in gradle files

have you tried gradle.properties or env variable  ?

What am using to access mine is this function in gradle.build

```
String getConfigurationProperty(String envVar, String sysProp, String defaultValue) {
    def result = System.getenv(envVar) ?: project.findProperty(sysProp)
    result ?: defaultValue
}
```

and then i have local variable to retrive the values , wither from env variable or gradle.properties

```
artifactoryUser = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_USER", "artifactoryUser", null)
artifactoryPwd = getConfigurationProperty("ARTIFACTORY_PWD", "artifactoryPwd", null)
```

where **ARTIFACTORY_USER** is enviroment var and **artifactoryUser** is gradle.properties variable .

and my gradle.properties look like this

```
artifactoryUser=user
artifactoryPwd=pass
```

make sure to add the gradle.properties to .gitignore if your using on Project level . or use on global level at **%USER%/.gradle/gradle.properties** if your using windows , **$HOME/. gradle/gradle.properties or ( ~/. gradle/gradle.properties )** if your using Linux/ubuntu .